Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry after installing Ubuntu 24.04
Hope you are doing well. The problem started to show up after I upgraded Ubuntu 23.10 ---> Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (through the Gnome Software Updater).
Here is the output of the sudo apt update -y command:
$ sudo apt update -y
Hit:1 https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
19 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu'

Disorder parts:
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir/ubuntu'


Landed here while doing the same from a Digital Ocean droplet. My issue is slightly different because the mirror is maintained by Digital Ocean and I have no idea how to fix it. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/n-missing-signed-by-in-the-sources-list-5-entry-for-http-mirrors-digitalocean-com-ubuntu

It's only a "notice" (N:), so not urgent.

Ran into this myself yesterday. I solved the issue as follows:

I'm in New Zealand, so I use http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, not the more generic http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu. For some reason, the update to 24.04 re-set the URLs to the generic, non-regional URL. Prefixing nz. to all URLs in all files named archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-* in /etc/apt/sourced.d.list/ got me a step further.
I copied the Signed-By: line mentioned in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources to all archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-* files in the same directory. This works, because the URL in ubuntu.sources is the regional nz.archive.ubuntu.com I now copy-pasted to all the archive_* files in the previous steps.
Running sudo apt update then gave me a bunch of warnings, similar to

W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-impish.sources:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:1


Checking the offending file archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-impish.sources showed that it was indeed basically a duplicate of the contents of ubuntu.sources, so I moved it out of the way (sudo mv archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-impish.sources ~/)

After all this, I could run sudo apt update without errors/warnings.
I'm not 100% sure what the URL should be in your case. Have a look what's there in ubuntu.sources. It could be worth looking for a faster one on the mirror list. Looking under Iran I'd think that Saba Abr Mizban or Tegra host should be much faster than the one you're currently using.

In my case what helped is removing the country prefix from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.
So it was before
[…]
URIs: http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
[…]

and then it became:
[…]
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
[…]

I am not exactly sure what's causing it (perhaps some missing key?), but it's clearly some misconfiguration on the Ubuntu 24.04 installer side.

Not worked here... Example of file:
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
just removing the br didn't make it work

Taking the hint from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/n-missing-signed-by-in-the-sources-list-5-entry-for-http-mirrors-digitalocean-com-ubuntu I added:
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

To each entry in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ file, that being for gb.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com in my case.  That's fixed the error and all sources are now downloaded and verified.
I assume I ran into this due to it being an old, upgraded multiple times, install, including that I probably hand-adjusted the sources file at some point.  It was still the old "just a single line per source" style before this upgrade from LTS 22, through 23, to LTS 24.

For Pop!_OS 24.04 alpha I added that to system.sources and added Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/pop-archive-keyring.gpg to pop-os-apps.sourcesand pop-os-release.sources

I had to do the same in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources for my Contabo server, adding the Signed-By lines which were missing.


Find sources that contain us.archive.ubuntu.com
grep -r "us.archive.ubuntu.com" /etc/apt/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/us_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.sources:URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/us_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.list.save:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/us_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.list.distUpgrade:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble multiverse


Edit us_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.sources file by adding Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg to the end of the file.
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/us_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu.sources
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg



NOTE: I edited only one file, not all!

For serverloft.eu urls, my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources file now looks like this, after simply adding the last line, and now the warnings are gone:
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://ubuntu.mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


For aliyun mirror, I add the following line to the end of third-party.sources to fix this problem. But I wonder if I should ask for the GPG from Aliyun mirror site?

cat third-party.sources

Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://mirrors.aliyuncs.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-security noble-backports noble-proposed
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-by: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

UBUNTU 24.04.1 After Install (UEFI) =

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

copy paste this =

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse

Control X for exit, Y for Yes to save, enter, now =

sudo apt update
