Settings says I'm on "development branch" -- how do I get to stable?
I upgraded to 24.04 development branch in april. Since then I've kept the system updated. Today, in Settings, it says I have "Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch)".
What should I do to not be on the "development branch"? My impression was that I only had to keep upgrading with apt for this to happen.
I tried do-release-upgrade, apt full-upgrade, rebooting twice. Couldn't see any difference.

Update
lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch)
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

This doesn't seem right.
Output of apt update:
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease       
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease     
Get:4 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com noble InRelease [41.3 kB]              
Get:5 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com noble-updates InRelease [41.3 kB]
Fetched 82.7 kB in 1s (89.4 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com'

Missing Signed-By -- is that the reason?
Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list:
# Ubuntu sources have moved to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

The new sources format looks easier to read, but I'm not sure what's supposed to be there.
Update 2
$ apt policy base-files
base-files:
  Installed: 13ubuntu9
  Candidate: 13ubuntu9
  Version table:
 *** 13ubuntu9 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


@user535733 Thanks. Added that info.

What does apt policy base-files show?

@steeldriver Added to Q

Hmm... so I'm seeing the current version as 13ubuntu10 - maybe the se.archive.ubuntu.com mirror is not quite up to date?

Check your Software & Updates control panel. Look at the Updates tab. The "Subscribed to:" line should be set on "Security and recommended updates"

@user535733 Thank you for the suggestion. I've followed it (it was set to security only, but I can't even recall having seen this dropdown menu before), and did an upgrade of all packages. Unfortunately, after a reboot, it did not result in the removal of the "development" text in the system UI or from lsb_release. The Missing Signed-By message is still present when doing apt update. I'm guessing I can safely ignore the OS description string going forward, and not treat it as an indication of a problem?

So far as I can tell, base-files 13ubuntu10 is in the noble repo (not noble-updates nor noble-security). Does apt policy base-files still show only version 13ubuntu9? Because when I curl the file list from http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/base-files/ directly, I can clearly see base-files_13ubuntu10_amd64.deb

@steeldriver Yes, that's right -- same output for apt policy base-files. I've never made myself familiar with that command or its output, so I'll defer to your judgment. No one has yet claimed that it's related, but I guess I'll have to follow https://askubuntu.com/q/1516700/428527 to get rid of the "Signed-By" message...


Removed all ddebs* source files
Temporarily removed language code from all URLs in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
Updated and restarted

Seems to have solved it
